# Parsing nested json using groovy script

Tags: groovy

I am trying to parse json using groovy script.

Source JSON -

```html
{
    "merchant_id": "merchant_id",
    "update_product_request": [
        {
            "store_id": "Store_ID1",
            "update_product_request_list": [
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014442",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Non-Weighable"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014443",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Weighable"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "update_product_request": [
        {
            "store_id": "Store_ID2",
            "update_product_request_list": [
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014442",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Non-Weighable"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014444",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Weighable_Packed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Groovy Script

```js
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def Message processData(Message message) {
  def json = message.getBody(java.lang.String)
  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
  def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(json)

  object.update_product_request.each.object.update_product_request.update_product_request_list.each {
    item - >
      item.quantity = item.quantity.replaceAll("0.000", "0");
    if (item.quantity != null && !item.quantity.isEmpty()) {
      item.quantity = item.quantity.toInteger().intValue()
    } else {
      item.quantity = 0. toInteger().intValue()
    }
    if (item.original_price != null && !item.original_price.isEmpty()) {
      item.original_price = item.original_price.toDouble().intValue()
    } else {
      item.original_price = 0. toDouble().intValue()
    }
    if (item.sale_price != null && !item.sale_price.isEmpty()) {
      item.sale_price = item.sale_price.toDouble().intValue()
    } else {
      item.sale_price = 0. toDouble().intValue()
    }
  }
  message.setBody(JsonOutput.toJson(object))
  return message
}
```

Output -

```html
{
    "merchant_id": "merchant_id",
    "update_product_request": [
        {
            "store_id": "Store_ID2",
            "update_product_request_list": [
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014442",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Non-Weighable"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014444",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Weighable_Packed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Required output -

```html
{
    "merchant_id": "merchant_id",
    "update_product_request": [
        {
            "store_id": "Store_ID1",
            "update_product_request_list": [
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014442",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Non-Weighable"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014443",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Weighable"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "update_product_request": [
        {
            "store_id": "Store_ID2",
            "update_product_request_list": [
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014442",
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Non-Weighable"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "bar_code": "9014444","
                    "product_identifier": "009-057820",
                    "original_price": 20,
                    "sale_price": 15,
                    "uom": "g",
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "size": "100",
                    "weight_type": "Weighable_Packed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with few other groovy variation on the same line.
Structure is nested and that i why I am using 2 for each lopes one inside another.

With each loop i am trying to iterate over collection.
I think my groovy script is not considering the loop and it printing only the last object

Comment: it's impossible to have in json-object (groovy map) repeating keys. after parsing you will have just one key named `update_product_request`

Comment: Your required output is ill-formed as JSON as well (not just as a Groovy Map). You can't have two different properties in the same JSON object with the same name.